# How to clear an ILayer?

Tags: arcobjects

I can clear all the layers using mapControl.ClearLayers(), but I only want to clear one layer (a sublayer of a basemap, like cities).  I'm new at this, thanks in advance.

edit: i am using C#

Comment: arcobjects has several apis. Is this c#? VB? Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure of which API you are using, but I know C# well. When you add layers you usually attach a name to the property. You can either choose it by the name, or the index.

```
mapControl.Layers[1].Clear();
mapControl.Layers["My Layer"].Clear();
```